# Django. Подскажите, что за ошибка при открытии модели на сайте. Модель таблицы-связки

Tags: django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за ошибка при открытии модели на сайте через админа. Модель таблицы-связки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> ProgrammingError at /admin/cannabis/drugformation/
>   column drug_formation.id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "drug_formation"."id", "drug_formation"."fk_drug", "d...
>                  ^
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cannabis/drugformation/
>   Django Version: 1.11.12
>   Exception Type: ProgrammingError
>   Exception Value:
>   column drug_formation.id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "drug_formation"."id", "drug_formation"."fk_drug", "d...
>                  ^
>   Exception Location: /Users/Sabina/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
>   Python Executable:  /Users/Sabina/djangogirls/myvenv/bin/python
>   Python Version: 3.6.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['/Users/Sabina/djangogirls',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
>    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
>    '/Users/Sabina/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Mon, 6 Aug 2018 09:32:18 +0300

Comment: Колонки, из которой вы пытаетесь выбрать данные не существует, посмотрите на ответ от @floydya

Answer (score 2):

Выполните миграцию:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: не помогло(( но спасибо!)

Comment: @Sabina попробуйте закомментировать это поле в модели, выполнить эти 2 команды. Затем раскомментировать и повторить выполнение команд снова.